# I can't include a boost header file mapped_file.hpp in my project

Tags: c++, boost

I need to include "\boost\iostreams\device\mapped_file.hpp" in my project. I tried: 
    #include <\boost\iostreams\device\mapped_file.hpp>,
but it couldn't work. Therefore, I used:
    #include "C:\path\boost\iostreams\device\mapped_file.hpp".
As a result, the system could find "mapped_file.hpp" file. However, when I build the project, the system complains:
    C:\path\boost\iostreams\device\mapped_file.hpp(14): fatal error C1083: 
    Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory
This tells me the way I fixed the first error is incorrect.

I have another project downloaded from a repository that uses boost library. This project is already built successfully in my PC. Everything for the boost library in my PC comes from this project, and the header file I need to use is located in "C:\path\boost\iostreams\device\mapped_file.hpp". In this case, how should I add a path or include "\boost\iostreams\device\mapped_file.hpp" to fix my current problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The commands used to compile the two projects would be relevant details to add. (Alternatively, certain project settings could be supplied, but how to find the right settings depends upon which IDE you use.) Presumably one of the commands tells the compiler where to find the Boost headers and the other doesn't. Even if you don't recognize where this is done, someone here might. Also, [the Boost documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#build-a-simple-program-using-boost) might help.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2012. I have searched this board for an answer, and tried to add a path to the boost library root by going to Project properties → C/C++ → General → Additional Include Directories. However, The boost library in my PC is from the other project. Therefore, it is not physically installed in my PC.

Comment: C:\path\boost is my PC. This is the boost library from the other project. I think somehow I should be able to use this library by adding a path somewhere.

Comment: I would think the "somewhere" is Project properties → C/C++ → General → Additional Include Directories. Did that not work? If not, try leaving off the last "boost", so just `C:\path`.

Comment: I add C:\path to both Project properties → C/C++ → General → Additional Include Directories and Project properties → linker → General → Additional library ---> Directories, but it still complains: Cannot open included file: '\boost\iostreams\device\mapped_file.hpp'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to include "\boost\iostreams\device\mapped_file.hpp" in my project.

Actually, no, you don't. You might need to include `"boost\iostreams\device\mapped_file.hpp"` (no leading slash) in your project, but that leading slash will make it impossible for the compiler to find the header file (unless you installed boost to your root directory – rather rare).

In addition, make sure the compiler knows to look in `C:\path\` for included headers. As discussed in the comments, this can be done in Visual Studio 2012 via Project properties → C/C++ → General → Additional Include Directories.